# Como Organizar de Forma Apropriada Tabelas em um Sistema

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para uma escola onde o professor criará a prova pelo sistema, tenho 3 entidades: Prova, Questao, Alternativa, gostaria de saber a melhor forma (no banco de dados) para salvar a alternativa correta? 
Ex: em que tabela ficaria a resposta: Questao ou Alternativa, gostaria de fazer o relacionamento de forma apropriada.

Comment: Você já planejou quais atributos terão cada *Entidade*?

Comment: Já sim, mas de forma bem básica, os atributos serão
Prova
-Titulo
Questao
-Enunciado
-Prova_id
Alternativa
-Alternativa
-Questao_id

Comment: Teria uma "perna" do aluno , ou seja as respostas , como modelou ?

Comment: isso é só pra o professor que está criando a prova, quando terminar, ter um jeito de saber quais são as questões corretas

Comment: A outra parte da modelagem poderia ajudar em sqls mais simples. A ideia que me ocorre seria uma coluna em Alternativa do tipo CORRETA S ou N , teria de ter uma validação para garantir só uma resposta correta , a solução simpkes uma coluna em Questao.

Comment: me parece uma abordagem interessante, vou ver como fazer, obrigado! qualquer coisa comunico aqui!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu Criaria;

1 - Prova (CodProva, Data, Materia, Pontos)
2 - ProvaQuestao (CodQuestao, CodProva, Texto)
3 - ProvaQuestaoAlternativa (CodAlternativa,CodQuestao,Texto,AlternativaCorreta(Sim ou Nao))

Algo nesse sentido.